# Newton's Method Not Working - Future Value Growing Annuity

Tags: python, newtons-method

My code for Newton's Method is divergent.

I'm trying to solve for an unknown interest rate (to a high level of precision) using Newton's Method in the Future Value of a Growing Annuity Due (Immediate) Formula, after starting with a 'pretty close guess.' However, my code is divergent (i.e. the answer below should be 10% if it's working properly. The formula is fv = (1 + i) * pp * ((1 + i) ** n - (1 + g) ** n) / (i-g).

```
fv = 735.30
pp = 100
i = .095 #starting guess
g = .05
n = 5

def newton_raphson_method(fv,pp,i,g, n):
    newton_raphson_i = i
    for num in range(1,15):
        newton_raphson_i = i - (((1+i)*pp*((1+i) ** n - (1+g) ** n ) - fv * i + fv *g) / ((n+1) * pp *(1+i)**n - fv))
        i = newton_raphson_i
newton_raphson_method(fv,pp,i,g, n)
```

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but Newton-Raphson method _may_ diverge depending on the shape of the curve and your starting point. Simpler algorithms such as bisection might be more suitable to use in such cases.

Comment: It works for me. The only thing is that you forgot the `return(i)` statement when you are defining the function;

Comment: Gene, it does get pretty accurate values where i is positive, but gets wacky when i is negative, leading me to believe I either don't understand the behavior of the function, or have gotten the partial derivative wrong, or both (i.e. fv = 551.16, pp = 100, i = -.73, g = .325273 and n = 11. If you try an initial guess of say -.7 for i, if returns -2.24, which is off by leaps and bounds